# Symfony2, Twig, Routes, Create valid url from twig with slug

Tags: forms, search, symfony, twig, routes

question is how to create such route as hpp://localhost/search/{searchString}

I played around but...

Simple form is (twig)

```
<form  class="form-search" action="{{ path ('site_search') }}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="string" value="{% trans %}Search{% endtrans %}..."/>
</form>
```

Route is

```
site_search:
    pattern:  /search/{string}
    defaults: { _controller: MainSiteBundle:Search:default, string: null }
    methods: [GET]
```

Now i get such url http://local.site/search?string=some but i want get http://local.site/search/some

Or what is the best solution for _GET form url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way html works .. form method **get** will append *?inputname=inputvalue* and **post** will send a post request to the given action url. ( but not append something to the action like */inputvalue* )

you could change the form action dynamically with javascript or use a RewriteRule in your webserver configuration in order to achieve what you're looking for.

A url rewrite might be the better option in my oppinion. Users directly accessing /search/term will not be redirected, users submitting the form will and therefore see the correct url in their browsers.

Why not just use `method="post"` and inside your action redirect the user to */search/term*.

```
public function searchAction($string = null, Request $request)
{
    if ( !($request->get('string') && !($string) ) {
         // ... render your form here 

         // return form
    }

    // ... perform search here 
    // return search results
}
```

That's how search is usually implemented with a form. Post the search-term get redirected to the results.

Comment: So only javascript or ModRewrite, ic. And what about other ways of 'creating search url'?

Comment: you can use a post request and redirect your user to the /search/term url from inside your application. updated my answer

Comment: post + redirect is anotherway out but better will be ModRewrite, we'll avoid redirect page-to-page... anyway thnx

Comment: You could use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) to modify the `<form>` element before submiting it. That way you would have the desired URL.